# Why does taking median fail in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have the following array in Matlab:

```
x = [15.618, 6.758, 4.273, 6.328, 94.995, 3.966, 6.334, 21.821,  5.402]
```

If I call `mean(x)` it works but when I call `median(x)` I'm getting the following error message:

> Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Does somebody see the reason for it?

Comment: Did you define a variable named `median` in your workspace ? MATLAB is probably thinking you want elements from that variable when you call `median(x)`

Comment: Now I don't think so. How can I check if I have defined such a variable?

Comment: `whos median` will tell you about variable and `which -all median` can find what files with the name are available to MATLAB

Comment: That was the problem, thank you for the solution. Perhaps I'm overworked.